# How to return back from one fragment to previous ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to return back from one `fragment` to previous `ActionBarActivity` on clicking `Navigartion Bar` back button?

Is there any method to override? I can't use `onBackPressed()` method inside fragment.

Comment: Do you want to go back another activity from your fragment activity which holds current fragments?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by override the OnBackPressed()

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack();
}
```

fragment is add in a stack when you popbackStack() it go to previous fragment in stack

Comment: you cant override onBackPressed event in fragments.

Comment: its unable to override onBackPressed() inside the Fragment so i want some alternative

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `onBackPressed()` from `Activity`.it will works.!

**Second thing**

You have to add `Fragment1` in BackStack if you want back on `Fragment1` when you replace With `ListFragent`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,
                FragmentObj);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: i haven't used  onBackPressed() inside the Activity class

Answer (score 0):

try using like this:

```
 getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                // handle back button
                //add the functionality here

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Implement it in your onResume function.

It should work perfectly.